# How do I unsubscribe from inner observables in redux observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6, redux-observable, unsubscribe

In the following epic I am listening to an action$ stream and then also listening to an auth stream `authState(app.auth())`

```
export const fetchAuthStatus = action$ =>
      action$.pipe(
        ofType(AUTH_STATUS_CHECKED),
        switchMap(() => authState(app.auth())),
        switchMap(user =>
          user
            ? of({ type: 'SIGNED_IN', payload: user })
            : signIn(googleAuthProvider)
        ),
        catchError(error => console.log('problems signing in'))
      );
```

It works as expected, the only problem is that if I change the auth status by logging out then the epic fires the `signIn()` method since `user`is no longer available.

How do I stop listening to `authState(app.auth())` once I have signed in. Where does the unsubscribe logic go in an epic?

Comment: Could you just take the first element from `authState(app.auth())` by applying the operator `take(1)` on the returned Observable? I.e. 
```switchMap(() => authState(app.auth()).pipe(take(1))),```

Comment: Thank you. So adding take(1) works well for the first time I login, but if I logout and then try and log back in nothing.

Comment: I assumed that there would have been another `AUTH_STATUS_CHECKED` action when you re-login. The new action would then have started a new `authState(app.auth()) observable in the `switchMap`. But if the `AUTH_STATUS_CHECKED` action is triggered only once, this won't work of course. Could you describe a bit more how your login/logout process should work?

Comment: I wanted a button to log people in and then another button to log people out. that's pretty much it. The if/else above is because the login button either logs you in or shows you an 0Auth modal depending on whether you have an already authenticated this session. For example, if you log in and then refresh the page, you dont need to log in again, it knows the session is valid.

Comment: I think, you have two logical actions in one here. One should check authorisation on page load, the other should react on login button. Split that into two and you'll get what you need

Comment: (imho, action on the login button click could be split as well. So at the end you get 3 actions: 1. check auth at app start, 2. login user 3. OAuth for logged in user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Epics are supposed to stay alive as long as your app is running.**

You don't complete them, you **mute them**.

To mute a stream there are a lot of possibilities. For example, [`windowToggle`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/windowToggle/) operator will let you mute your observable by another streams, say, by streams of other events.

E.g. you mute the epic while in-between `SIGN_IN` — `SIGN_OUT` sequence. And unmute in `SIGN_OUT` — `SIGN_IN` period.

Heres an article on [different pausing strategies with rxjs](https://medium.com/@kddsky/pauseable-observables-in-rxjs-58ce2b8c7dfd).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Kos, so how would I mute this specific example?

Comment: And when you say epics always run does that mean redux-observables handles unsubscribing when the app unmounts? If not won't thise lead to a memory leak?

Comment: @JoshPittman, well, its a responsibility of the library to init completion of the `action$` stream. You don't have yo worry about that.